# Magento 1.6.1 module on localhost

Tags: magento

IN LOCALHOST:
Using:
openSUSE 11.4 (x86_64)
Linux 2.6.37.6-0.9-desktop x86_64
php 5.3.5-5.16.1
apache 2.2.17-4.9.1
mysql 5.3.5-5.16.1
magento 1.6.1.0

Following the tutorials: http://alanstorm.com/magento_config
up to http://magento.example.com/?showConfig=true

Testing I just come to frontpage using: localhost/ecomm/magento/?showConfig=true

Anyone who can tell me what is wrong and why I do not get the listing?
Does it have anything to do with using localhost?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of downsides to using localhost for magento. The following thread should help you through it:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/214962/